# Converting a part of web application built with Javascript/Jquery to Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

We would like to upgrade the web application built with Java script and Jquery to Angular 2. The application is huge and we cannot convert it at one shot, so we would like to convert it in a step by step basis. I have a couple of questions

1. What are options to convert a small part of web application to Angular 2.
2. From the current web application(built with simple java script / jquery) we would like to have a link that would open a modal window built in Angular 2. The modal window will have a series of screens to capture user input. We just want to create this part alone in Angular 2 as a first step. Is this possible?

Comment: you have a Java script or a javascript ?

Comment: Yes it is javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS can be used in small parts of your main application. No problems there. You can write your modal logic using angular and you will be fine. You can always add new features in your app using angular, going forward.

However when you say you want to upgrade your existing code, more factors will come into play and a lot will depend on the existing architecture of your app.

The most significant difference is that most jQuery apps works around DOM manipulation. The code you write for jQuery is always trying to manipulate your DOM.

But in angular this process works differently. If you code correctly you will rarely need to manipulate DOM in your angular project.

So I would not recommend to go for a partial upgrade where you have to mess with your application's architecture. But certainly you can build new features using Angular.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Varun. It will be a humongous change to upgrade the complete project. So we wanted to convert in small steps. The functionality part of the modal window is completely independent and we wanted to upgrade it. Can i create a new web application with the features of modal window and link it to the existing application. That way users can access the features of modal window from existing application, behind scenes the modal window will be running on Angular 2.

Comment: Personally I would never do that simply because I like to keep things under same roof if I can. Technically you can do this. Nothing wrong in this approach that I can see. So the choice boils down to the scale. If your new app/feature has relatively few lines of code then why create a separate app. If your new feature is a full blown app in itself then go for a separate module

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between jQuery and Angular2. jQuery is a library to mainly manipulate the DOM. Whereas Angular2 is a complete framework. When I say complete framework, it has features like routing. So it is easy to build single page application with Angular2 without much external dependency.

To move to Angular2 you might need changes in the server-side also, like exposing APIs, the build system to support Angular2.

So instead of moving a modal window to angular2, a better option might to go with a microframework based approach, were you identify a small independent set of functionalities(module) and move it to Angular2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The functionality that is part of modal window is completely independent, so thought of moving that part to Angular 2. Also, we are making changes to server side code for that functionality part of a project, so thought of upgrading the UI as part of the project. So, the idea is to create the modal window, the UI code and server code completely separate for this functionality. In that process we want to upgrade the existing modal window to Angular 2. Is it possible to traverse from the existing application to Angular 2 modal window using a link.